# How to print out all substrings of a string?

Tags: java, loops, substring

I searched around and couldn't find this problem listed anywhere and
I spent some time trying to make it work with two loops, but couldn't. I would be interested in anything shorter and more elegant. This is an exercise, but not a homework problem and as the title says I'm supposed to keep it simple i.e. no arrays/list/hash etc.

My work so far:

```
    String str = "string";
    String subString;
    int k = 1;

    while (k <= str.length()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            for (int j = i+1; j <= str.length(); j++) {

                subString = str.substring(i,j);

                if (subString.length()==k) {System.out.println(subString);}

            }               
        }

        k++;

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the substrings?  The logic in your two most inner loops (over `i` and `j`) actually looks correct.  If you were to just print out `substring` you would have covered every substring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need 2 nested loops, not 3. You don't need `k` and `j` at the same time.

```
String str = "string";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(i, j));
    }               
}
```

Output:

```
s
st
str
stri
strin
string
t
tr
tri
trin
tring
r
ri
rin
ring
i
in
ing
n
ng
g
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of 3 loops and checking substring size everytime:
[Demo:](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/4flCdF)

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k+i <= str.length(); k++) {
            subString = str.substring(i,k+i);
            System.out.println(subString);
        }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw a couple of similar answers, but this one should have the same output as the original 3-loop version:

```
String str = "string";
String subString;
for (int k = 1; k <= str.length(); k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i+k <= str.length(); i++) {
        subString = str.substring(i,i+k);
        System.out.println(subString);
    }               
}
```